# Need a way to generate Java classes for Spring Boot

Tags: java, database, spring, code-generation, mybatis

I’m trying to build an administration portal accessible via web starting from the informations inside a database using Spring Boot with MyBatis for accessing the database. I wanted to find a way to reuse the code that I’m building for the portal with any other type of database, so I was wondering if there was a way to automatically generate classes for my project starting from the informations in the database, for example table names and fields...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

**Telosys** code generator (http://www.telosys.org) does this kind of job.

It uses the database schema to create a lightweight model that is used to generate the code (Java or any other language).

For more information see : https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/

Everything is Open Source (tool and templates)

Answer (score 1):

An option could be Jassd, which generates POJOs, Dao interfaces, and Dao implementation classes from a database.  Use what you want from the output and discard the rest, the aim of this project was to not have to manually write getters and setters and have something to start from.

See the documentation and sample output at https://github.com/aforslund/jassd

(Note: I am the author, implemented this library to be able to get plain old Java objects generated and bootstrap som Dao/DaoImplementation classes using plain SQL and JDBCTemplate with Spring Boot).

Answer (score 0):

If it is to switch db and reuse the code, simply changing these values in application.properties should help. If you have MySQL in development environment and postgres in production, that can also be handled. Check the following link for more details

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Probably I didn’t explain my self well. I looked at the link you posted but it only refers to changing the database with another one but if the new database has a different structure it won’t work. The thing that I’m trying to do is to find a way to automatically modify the code according to the new structure of the database that I use.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Mario. I am just wondering if setting  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update would help you achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky! I just release cgV19 at https://github.com/carstenSpraener/cgV19

With it you could implement a model loader which connects to your database and reads the table information. It than provides this information to cgV19 as a meta model.

the next step is to implement a "cartridge" for cgV19 where you can generate java classes from that meta model.

if you try it out please give me feedback on you progress.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use mybatis then [MyBatis Generator](https://mybatis.org/generator/) is your best bet:

> MyBatis Generator (MBG) is a code generator for MyBatis MyBatis and iBATIS. It will generate code for all versions of MyBatis, and versions of iBATIS after version 2.2.0. It will introspect a database table (or many tables) and will generate artifacts that can be used to access the table(s).
>
> MyBatis Generator will generate:
>
> - Java POJOs that match the table structure.
> - MyBatis/iBATIS Compatible SQL Map XML Files. MBG generates SQL for simple CRUD functions on each table in a configuration.
> - Java client classes that make appropriate use of the above objects.